# Grunt css Purge no output file

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

In the gruntfile.js i wrote:

```
  // Css Purge
  css_purge: {
  options: {
    "verbose": false,
    "no_duplicate_property": true,
  },
  files: {
   src: 'css/bigfile.css',
   dest: 'css/purged.css'
  },
 }
```

Just to test the bigFile.css is :

```
body {color: red;}
body, p {color:red;}
p {color: red; font-size: 24px;}
#test p {color: red;}
```

So terminal message is:

```
Running "css_purge:files" (css_purge) task
"css/" has been created

Thu May 12 2016 01:33:27 GMT-0400 (EDT) Success! css/bigfile.css : css/purged.css
```

But the new file purged.css is the same as bigFile.css

Comment: Would you be ok to post your css files?

Comment: Hey Louis, we just updated the core of CSS-Purge, it will do what you're asking: rbtech.github.io/css-purge, you can use it standalone in the meantime, until the grunt plugin is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figure it out. It removed only identical rules. So if I have exactly same rule it will be removed in output file. Is there a tool that remove extra css like in my exemple file `body,p {color:red;}` is extra code since I already have `body {color:red;}` ?

Comment: Hey Louis, we just updated the core of CSS-Purge, it will do what you're asking: http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge, you can use it standalone in the meantime, until the grunt plugin is updated